EF Core changes ID of entity on add. Entity cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked
I'm working on a library for generating random data for relational databases. I'm using reflection to add instances of entity in my DbContext because I cannot explicitly specify type of the instance.
public class EntityAdder<TDbContext> where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly MyOptions _options;

    public EntityAdder(TDbContext dbContext,
                       MyOptionsProvider optionsProvider)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _options = optionsProvider.GetOptions();
    }

    public async Task AddEntities(Dictionary<EntityInfo, List<object>> entities)
    {
        var dbSets = typeof(TDbContext)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
            .Select(x => new DbSetInfo
            {
                DbSet = x.GetGetMethod()!.Invoke(_dbContext, [])!,
                DbSetProperty = x,
                AddMethod = x.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add")!
            })
            .ToList();

        foreach (var (entity, pool) in entities)
        {
            var dbSet = dbSets.Single(x => x.DbSetProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == entity.EntityType);

            if (_options.OverrideExistingData)
            {
                clearDbSet(dbSet);
            }

            foreach (var entityObject in pool)
            {
                dbSet.AddMethod.Invoke(dbSet.DbSet, [entityObject]);
            }
        }

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private void clearDbSet(DbSetInfo dbSet)
    {
        MethodInfo removeRangeMethod = dbSet.DbSetProperty.PropertyType
            .GetMethods()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "RemoveRange")
            .ElementAt(1);
        removeRangeMethod.Invoke(dbSet.DbSet, [dbSet.DbSet]);
    }

    class DbSetInfo
    {
        public object DbSet { get; set; }
        public PropertyInfo DbSetProperty { get; set; }
        public MethodInfo AddMethod { get; set; }
    }
}

Entities:
public class TestEntity1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public bool Value3 { get; set; }
    public TestEntity2? Entity2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestEntity2
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public TestEntity1? Entity1 { get; set; } 
    public int? Entity1ID { get; set; }  
}

DbContext:
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext() { }
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<TestEntity1> Entity1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TestEntity2> Entity2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        if (builder.IsConfigured) return;

        builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

        builder.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDatabase");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<TestEntity1>()
            .HasKey(e => e.ID);
        builder.Entity<TestEntity2>()
            .HasKey(e => e.ID);

        builder.Entity<TestEntity1>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Entity2)
            .WithOne(e => e.Entity1)
            .HasForeignKey<TestEntity2>(e => e.Entity1ID);
    }
}

EntityInfo class contains some useful information about entity like type, number of instances etc. which is, in my opinion, not relevant to the problem.
ID of the first instance in the pool is 0, but when trying to add it to the dbSet it suddenly changes to 1. Then, when adding next instance with ID of 1, the exception is thrown because ID of first instance was changed to 1:

The instance of entity type 'TestEntity1' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{ID: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

First step of iteration:

After adding:

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Simple answer: ID of an entity cannot be zero
